# Getting the number of instances of a value in a dictionary

Tags: c#, lambda

How to get the number of instances of the value in a dictionary that contains list of strings with lambda expressions?

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Below needs to be improved to get rid of error; Basically can't compare a string to a list of strings.

```
int count = dict.Values.Count(v => v == "specific value");
```

Comment: Like error says you are comparing List<string> to string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use this version:

```
int count = dict.Count(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains("specific value"));
```

[EDIT] Ok, here's some results comparing the `Contains()` approach with the `SelectMany()` approach (x86 release build):

n1 = 10000, n2 = 50000:

```
Contains() took: 00:00:04.2299671
SelectMany() took: 00:00:13.0385700
Contains() took: 00:00:04.1634190
SelectMany() took: 00:00:12.9052739
Contains() took: 00:00:04.1605812
SelectMany() took: 00:00:12.8953210
Contains() took: 00:00:04.1356058
SelectMany() took: 00:00:12.9109115
```

n1 = 20000, n2 = 100000:

```
Contains() took: 00:00:16.7422573
SelectMany() took: 00:00:52.1070692
Contains() took: 00:00:16.7206587
SelectMany() took: 00:00:52.1910468
Contains() took: 00:00:16.6064611
SelectMany() took: 00:00:52.1961513
Contains() took: 00:00:16.6167020
SelectMany() took: 00:00:54.5120003
```

For the second set of results I have doubled both n1 and n2, which results in four times the number of strings in total.

Both algorithms' times have increased by a factor of 4, which indicates that they are both O(N) where N is the total number of strings.

And the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            var strings = new List<string>();

            int n1 = 10000;
            int n2 = 50000;

            for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
                strings.Add("TEST");

            for (int i = 0; i < n2; ++i)
                dict.Add(i.ToString(), strings);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                dict.Count(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains("specific value"));
                Console.WriteLine("Contains() took: " + sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();
                dict.Values.SelectMany(v => v).Count(v => v == "specific value");
                Console.WriteLine("SelectMany() took: " + sw.Elapsed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm just adding some timing tests. :)

Comment: yours might be the fastest ! haha

Comment: +1 for you, on all of my tests yours comes out on top and I'am still trying to figure out why.

Comment: I have to admit, I did think your's would be faster... Now I think that they are both O(N) where N is the total number of strings.

Comment: you win, yours is faster..already gave you a +1, i think it's faster because yours eliminates the huge list I have to go through later on..

Comment: I'll go ahead and add another set of results for interest's sake, because it shows that for *both* methods increasing the total number of strings by a factor of 4 increases the time taken by 4 as well.

Answer (score 5):

using linq ? sure.

```
 dict.Values.SelectMany( v => v).Where( v => v == "specific value").Count();
```

i.e:

```
dict.Values.SelectMany( v => v).Count(  v => v == "specific value" );
```

Comment: I'm not convinced it is either actually, im running some tests now and the results are interesting. I would assume that SelectMany does 1 pass and Count does another pass making it O(2n) which is still linear...